# Quotes around hypothetical questions?

Tags: quotes

I'm unsure about how to punctuate the last part of this sentence. Specifically, I'm don't know what to do about the hypothetical questions. Do I put quotes around them? Do I put a period after the last one? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

> Before an important scene, writers often pause the story and take a snapshot to answers the questions that we, the readers, have about the scene. **Questions like, What do the surroundings look like? What objects do we see? Where are these objects located? F Scott Fitzgerald takes it one step further.**

Comment: Are you asking about one particular sentence , or the (highlighted) last part of the whole paragraph?

Comment: What you have works fine. They are not quotes, but your thoughts about what Fitzgerald is setting up.

Comment: @Spencerthe the bolded part

Answer (score 1):

Since these questions are more representative rather than specific questions, quotes would not be used. By this I mean it seems that you intend the reader not to ask those exact questions verbatim, but rather those questions generalize or paraphrase the types of questions that readers are expected to ask.

See: https://auis.edu.krd/quotations-and-paraphrasing